# Add To Bytes without overflow

Tags: c#, algorithm, byte

For some API Integration, I have an operation where I need to add two bytes and get a single byte as a result. It's some kind of a checksum.  Now by nature there can happen overflows.

For example

```
byte a = 0xff
byte b = 0x01
byte results = a + b;
```

Is there a simple built-in syntax to avoid overflows to move on to the next bytes or do I have to do this on my own? e.g. subtract full bytes and so on?
Didn't find an API for this, did I overlook something?

Comment: You can use [`checked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked) to explicitly enable overflow checking, or [`unchecked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unchecked) to explicitly disable overflow checking. In short, in a `checked` block/ statement the runtime will throw a `OverflowException` if the addition overflows, in an `unchecked` block/ statement the addition will just silently overflow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you add `byte`s the result, however, is `int`, e.g.

```
byte a = 100;
byte b = 200;

var result = a + b; // result == 300
```

Since both `a` and `b` are in `0..255` range the result will be in `0..510` range and *no integer overflow is possible*. But you want `byte result` and that's why you need a cast:

```
byte result = (byte) (a + b);
```

Here, .net can show *two* types of reaction:

- *check* ans throw [overflow exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.overflowexception?view=net-6.0)
- do not *check* and ignore overflow: `256 -> 0`, `257 -> 1` etc.

We want second option and that's why `unchecked`:

```
byte result = unchecked((byte) (a + b));
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, C# doesn't check for integral overflows so this should just work.

However, if the project has enabled integral overflow checking you can suppress it for a code block by using the [`unchecked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unchecked) keyword, for example:

```
byte a = 0xff
byte b = 0x01

unchecked
{
    byte results = (byte) a + b;
}
```

Or

```
byte results = (byte) unchecked(a + b);
```